# reactjs modulus not working

Tags: reactjs, modulus

I am looping through a set of items in a reactjs component. I'm trying to wrap the items in a div every 3 items.

```
            {
              lang.carouselFeatures[0].items.map(function (item, index) {
                return (
                  {
                    index % 3 === 0
                      ? <div className='row'>
                      : null
                  }
                  <div key={index} className='medium-18 medium-offset-2 columns'>
                    <a rel='nofollow' href='#page-01-med'>
                      <div className='relative-container'>
                        <img className='icn__large icn--no-margin-bottom centered' src={Thumb1} />
                        <div className='icn--hover__features' />
                      </div>
                      <p className='text--center paragraph-margin-top-10'>Live Video Interviews</p>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  {
                    index % 3 === 0
                      ? </div>
                      : null
                  }
                )
              })
            }
```

I am trying to recreate this static piece of markup, so also need to add to the wrapper an additional class if its not the first series. Answers/Suggestions welcome. [image]

///fixed

```
    {
     lang.carouselFeatures[0].items.reduce((m, k, i) => {
       if (i % 3 === 0) {
         m.push([k])
       } else {
         m[m.length - 1].push(k)
       }
       return m
     }, []).map((grouped, index) => (
       <div key={index} className='row'>
         {
           grouped.map((item, j) =>
             <div key={j} className='medium-18 medium-offset-2 columns'>
               <a rel='nofollow' href='#page-01-med'>
                 <div className='relative-container'>
                   <img className='icn__large icn--no-margin-bottom centered' src={item.image} />
                   <div className='icn--hover__features' />
                 </div>
                 <p className='text--center paragraph-margin-top-10'>{item.title}</p>
               </a>
             </div>
            )
         }
       </div>
      ))
    }
```

Comment: Its throwing up an error at the % "Unexpected token"

Answer (score 1):

React expects you to return a React component. You cannot "split" a React component and return a closing tag where it fits.

What you do here reminds of the kind of logic you would do in languages such as `php` where you would just `echo` the html elements in text. In `php` that works because html is parsed at runtime and doesn't need compilation. This isn't the case with React.

Instead you need to return *one component at a time*, and to do that you need a slightly more complex algorithm. Here I use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control):

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      chunkSize: 3
    };
  }
  
  renderGroups() {
    let a = this.state.arr.reduce((acc, item, idx) => {
      let group = acc.pop();
      if (group.length == this.state.chunkSize) {
        acc.push(group);
        group = [];
      }
      group.push(item);
      acc.push(group);
      return acc;
    }, [[]]);
    
    return a.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div key={item} className='row'>
          {item.map(x => <div className='medium-18 medium-offset-2 columns'>{x}</div>)}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderGroups()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.row {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}

.columns {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

For a detailed explanation of what happens inside the `reduce()`, have a look at an earlier answer of mine, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks/43873342#43873342).

Comment: is there a simpler method here -- modifying my previous example -- I got like a json multi-dimensional array here

Comment: @TheOldCounty This is the simplest solution I know of. It's only 9 lines of code...

Comment: I'm having an issue mapping the items -- you seen my answer above?

Comment: I've tried to get to the grouped/items var but its busted in my above example

Answer (score 1):

Every Html like tag written in jsx is converted to plain javascript. In your code, Jsx element is broken as `<div>` is not a valid element. It should be either `<div/>` or `<div></div>`

You can group your data in map reduce chain like this:

```
{ 
 lang.carouselFeatures[0].items.reduce((m,k,i)=>{
  if(i%3==0){ 
     m.push([k]) 
  }else{ 
     m[m.length-1].push(k) 
  }
  return m;
 },[]).map(grouped=>(<div>{grouped}</div>))
}
```

Comment: I've tried to get to the grouped var but its busted in my above example

Comment: I forgot to split the grouped array. You need to use a second map in grouped. Edited the code in fiddle. Please check this : https://jsfiddle.net/parthapal33/4z5r0kcx/1/